# Apache rewrite rule which works with or without a trailing slash

Tags: regex, url, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect a series of static URLs, and I want it to work whether or not the trailing slash is present:

```
/foo/bar  --->  /tacos
/foo/bar/  -->  /tacos
```

I've tried the following, and all sorts of variations, but I always get a match only with the trailing slash present:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/bar?/$ http://url.com/tacos
RewriteRule ^foo/bar(?/)$ http://url.com/tacos
RewriteRule ^foo/bar*/$ http://url.com/tacos
RewriteRule ^foo/bar(*/)$ http://url.com/tacos
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Help?

Comment: Ran into the same issue. I noticed that if I had the folder existing (but empty) then both would work with "RewriteRule ^old/(.*) http://test.com/new/$1 [R=301,L]" logic (where test.com/old/ existed).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Other than in [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBNF) or [ABNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABNF), a quantifier in regular expressions refers the preceding expression and not the following expression.

**So:**

```
RewriteRule ^foo/bar/?$ http://url.com/tacos
```

Comment: The question mark says "I'll have 0 or 1 trailing slashes."  You go to a restaurant and say "I'll have a taco?"  You're really saying "I'll have 0 or 1 tacos."

Answer (score 14):

If you want to match foo/bar regardless of whether it's followed by another portion of path, you can say:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/bar(/.*|$) http://url.com/tacos
```

This will match any of the following:

```
foo/bar
foo/bar/
foo/bar/baz
```

It means:  match either a) a slash followed by 0 or more characters, or b) the end of the string.

On the other hand, these might be undesirable:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/bar/? http://url.com/tacos     # This also matches foo/barb
RewriteRule ^foo/bar/?$ http://url.com/tacos    # This will not match foo/bar/baz
```

Comment: I'd say you can omit the `.*` here: `RewriteRule ^foo/bar(/|$) http://url.com/tacos`. That only makes sense if you actually use what you capture there.

Comment: @arkascha True.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^foo/bar/?$ http://url.com/tacos
```

Answer (score 2):

This also works:
`RedirectMatch 301 /foo/bar(/.*|$) http://url.com/tacos`