# Make dynamic links (with ?) return error 404 not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dynamic, hyperlink, http-status-code-404

Using .htaccess (are there any other solutions?) is there a way to make all dynamic links (links containing the sign ?) of a site return a 404 not found response header?

For example:

http://www.example.com/?bla_bla - will return 404

http://www.example.com/test/index.html?no_redirect=true - will return 404

Comment: try removing the last slash before the question mark ;)

Comment: if you really need it, because yes, it is recommended, please take a look to this other answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843293/apache-rewrite-rule-which-works-with-or-without-a-trailing-slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're asking for any request containing a query string to return a 404. If that *is* what you want, use the below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
```

This will use the regex `.+` to check if there are one or more characters in the query string. If that condition is met, any path (`.*` matches 0 or more characters) will be redirected as a 404